# Nuxt js: Google maps markers wont show and loop is not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, google-maps-api-3, vuejs2

I have a function that loops over an object to populate the markers. But when I do run the code, the loop is not working. Also when I do `console.log`, it is not showing me anything even in Vue DevTools. I am not using any Vue packages for the Google map. I just followed the documentation, and wrote the vanilla JavaScript functions.

Here is the whole function:

```js
export default {
    layout:'adminLte',
    data(){
        return{
            address:{
                lat:7.0650673,
                lng:125.5961476
            },
            clinic:[],
            markersInfo:[],
        }
    },
    methods:{
        loadScript() {
            if (window.google && window.google.maps) {
                this.initMap();
                return;
            }
            var self = this;
            var script = document.createElement("script");
            script.onload = function() {
                if (!window.google && !window.google.maps)
                    return void(console.error("no google maps script included"));
                self.initMap();
            };
            script.async = true;
            script.defer = true;
            script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&libraries=geometry";
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
        },
        initMap(){

            var center = new google.maps.LatLng(this.address.lat, this.address.lng)
            const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 13,
                center: center
            })
    
            //this are for the markers. even if i console log below. it wont show anything
            for (var i = 0; i < this.clinic.length; i++) {
                var clinicLat = this.clinic.data[i].lat;
                var clinicLng = this.clinic.data[i].lng;
                var details = this.clinic.data[i].name;
                var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(clinicLat,clinicLng);
                console.log(details)
                var markers = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: map,
                    icon: {
                        url: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png"
                    },
                    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 20),
                });
                const contentString = '<div id="content"><p>' + details + '</p></div>';
                //for Info windows function
                console.log('Markers' + markers)
                this.infoWindowShow(markers, contentString);
                this.markersInfo.push(markers)
            }
      
        },
        infoWindowShow(markers, contentString) {
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: contentString
            });
            markers.addListener('click', function() {
                infowindow.open(markers.get('map'), markers);
            });
        },
        showMarker(id) {
            google.maps.event.trigger(this.markersInfo[id], 'click');
        },
        getClinicsList(){
              firebase.database().ref('clinics').on('value',(snapshot)=>{
                this.clinic = snapshot.val()
                console.log(snapshot.val())
                this.loadScript()
            })
        },
    },
    created(){
        console.log('created')
        this.getClinicsList()
 
        if (localStorage.getItem("user-email") === null) {
         this.$router.push('/login')
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        this.loadScript()
    }
}
```

The HTML element for map:

```html
<div class="card-body table-responsive">
  <div id="map" style="width: 1200px; height: 600px;"></div>
</div>
```

Still the DevTools is empty, but the `clinic` array has values.
[image: screenshot]

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5rbqs32z/2/)

Comment: Where is the HTML? CSS? You need to provide a [mcve], as usual... Read *minimal* **and** *complete*. *Expected mapDiv of type Element but was passed null* suggests that `document.getElementById('map')` doesn't exist.

Comment: As @MrUpsidown says the error clearly states that the element does not exist in the page. This is the case at the time your initMap() function is called. Are your script tags all up in the <head> element maybe, and therefore executing before the that html snippet has even been added to the DOM?

Comment: What element sir? The mapDiv thing? Also when i run the code i can see the map but the markers wont. Markers info array is always empty. The loop is not working

Comment: i dont know why downvote my question. Its just the loop is not working there that is what I asked. @MrUpsidown. I already fixed the error

Comment: I down-voted. Why? 1) You haven't provided a [mcve] 2) You should limit your question to 1 single problem 3) Your question should contain debugging details - I have no issue retracting my down-vote, or close-vote, if you edit your question so that it fits the requirements. We don't have your data. If the firebase stuff works, eliminate it from your question and provide raw sample data. Creating a stack-snippet, JSFiddle, Codesandbox, etc. allows you to bundle a small Vue app which will then be easy for anyone to debug. Why would we take the time to do that for you? You have an issue. Not us.

Comment: I dont know how to use the snippets sir @MrUpsidown andi i already edited and i have only one problem now

Comment: okay sir @MrUpsidown i am very sorry. I tried to replicate it using fiddle as possible and here is the link. please take a look https://jsfiddle.net/12uwheyt/

Comment: can we chat sir @tony19 i really need help for this one

Comment: Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the map markers even get created, the `for`-loop hits a runtime error, caused by a couple issues in your code.

### Issue 1: `clinic` is not an `Array`

As seen in the screenshot, `clinic` is actually set to an `Object`:

[image: clinic type]

The `for`-loop assumed `clinic` was an `Array`, and iterated with a numeric index, but that won't work properly with your `Object`. One solution is to use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) for iteration like this:

```js
// BEFORE:
// for (var i = 0; i < this.clinic.length; i++) {

for (const item of Object.values(this.clinic)) {
```

### Issue 2: `item.data` does not exist

Your loop is trying to access a nonexistent `data` prop in each `clinic` item (i.e., `var clinicLat = this.clinic.data[i].lat`), but the `lat` and `lng` props are actually at the root of the object, as seen in the screenshot:

[image: item format]

So you could just access the props directly from the item reference. Using the corrected `for`-loop from above:

```js
// BEFORE:
// for (var i = 0; i < this.clinic.length; i++) {
//   var clinicLat = this.clinic.data[i].lat;
//   var clinicLng = this.clinic.data[i].lng;
//   //...
// }

for (const item of Object.values(this.clinic)) {
  const clinicLat = item.lat
  const clinicLng = item.lng
  //...
}
```

[Working JSFiddle with changes above](https://jsfiddle.net/helloworld/r06mwt14/6/)

Comment: Ohh I see. Thats why the work doesnt work because i got an object. I really appreciate your help sir. Thanks for your time. Sorry for my fiddle, I was really trying to replicate as I can and this is my first time using fiddle

Comment: @Vince No problem :) Keep at it

Comment: thaks a lot sir really helps me. Thanks again :))